# How can I allow access to a single IP address via Nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

Nginx, Passenger, and Rails are running beautifully on my Linode. Before I launch, I'd like to restrict access so only my IP can view the site.

I've tried to deny access to all, and allow access to only my IP in Nginx. It does deny access to all, but I can't get the allow to work. I have checked to ensure the IP address I'm specifying in nginx.conf is my correct public ip.

Here's my nginx.conf. I've restarted nginx after editing the file, and tested some other changes which worked as expected (for instance, I removed deny all and was able to access the site, as expected).

What am I doing wrong?

```
    http {
      passenger_root /path/to/passenger-3.0.11;
      passenger_ruby /path/to/ruby;
      include       mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      sendfile        on;
      keepalive_timeout  65;
      gzip  on;
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.foo.bar;
        root /path/to/rails/public/;
        passenger_enabled on;
        location / {
          allow   my.public.ip.here;
          deny    all;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Not all that familiar with nginx config, but have you tried switching the order?  I would imagine what it's doing is granting access to your ip, and then denying access to all.  Your IP is included in all, so it's wiping the allow.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. From the [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule): "Note that the order of the deny/allow is of the utmost importance. If you're coming from the Apache world you might be tempted to think that you can switch the access directives order and everything will work. In fact it doesn't. Switching the order in the above example has the result of denying access to all addresses."

Answer (score 173, accepted):

modify your nginx.conf

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.foo.bar;

    location / {
      root /path/to/rails/public/;
      passenger_enabled on;

      allow   my.public.ip.here;
      deny    all;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Apparently it's important that allow is the first, deny is the second, otherwise deny is 'stronger'.

Comment: Whenever I add this above to my nginx.conf file I'm no longer able to restart nginx. I get this error: [....] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!   <<<<< Any idea what's going on with my build? @erkasraim

Comment: @Supplement try and see if you missed a comma at the end of the allow, or any other rule

Comment: hi, I have just one doubt, as our public ip changes on connection change/ location change, wont it be a headache to change the ip in nginx conf  each time the ip changes?
I am a bit confused.

Comment: @AniketSingla in that case, if you're on a private network, you can specify a CIDR block of the private network instead of a specific public IP address. Otherwise, you can look into the `ssl_verify_client` directive or basic HTTP authentication.