# Configure nginx to accept connection from a single host/ip on specific subdomain

Tags: nginx

I would like to know how to configure nginx to allow access to a single IP, for a subdomain.

Which means, all `*.domain.com` can be accessed by public, except `dev-stg.domain.com`

as you might have guessed, I am trying to reserve one subdomain for a pre-production check.

Comment: Add server block and use allow/deny directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the geo module:

```
geo $unknown_ip {
    default 1;
    192.0.2.1 0;  # or use CIDR notation
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        if ($unknown_ip) {
            return 403;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found [a better one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438867/how-can-i-allow-access-to-a-single-ip-address-via-nginx-conf) but +1 for the effort

Comment: If you ever need the same restriction in multiple locations or servers, I would reconsider using the geo module. The `$unknown_ip` variable is available throughout the config. Otherwise you would need to duplicate your allow/deny directives each place they're needed. Also easier to maintain.