# prevent nginx from routing traffic to another ec2 instance for unauthorized users

Tags: nginx, tcp, redis, stream

I have nginx server running on an ec2 instance. I am using a tcp connection to route the traffic from nginx to a redis instance and the configuration file is the following:-

```
events{}
stream {
  upstream redis {
  server **.***.***.**:80;
  }
    server {
    listen 80 so_keepalive=on;
    proxy_pass redis;
    }
}
```

according to this everyone can access my redis instance if they have the ip address of the nginx instance which is not a safe practice. Is there is a way to prevent unauthorized users from being routed to my redis database even if they know the ip address of the nginx instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the answer depends on the use case.

If its a small number of users, you can make exceptions based on ip addresses, which is considered as secure as it gets, using (within a location block):

```
allow allowed.ip.address.1;
allow allowed.ip.address.2;
deny all;
```

See these posts for implementation details:

- [How can I allow access to a single IP address via Nginx.conf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438867/how-can-i-allow-access-to-a-single-ip-address-via-nginx-conf)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/611311/restricting-multiple-directories-to-same-ip-ranges

If you need the service to be available to more users than you could manage ip addreses, you'll probably want to look into nginx auth or a similar third party equivalent: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/

Comment: thanks. Can you give an example about a third party equivalent ?

Comment: Not that familiar with those, but a simple google search suggests  https://github.com/cloudflare/nginx-google-oauth could work well if you can authenticate them by gmail.