# Access Private IP from Domain with NAT

Tags: ssl, nat

I'm working on centos 8 and using Nginx, also certbot for SSL. I need to make an access from specific IP that when hit to my domain (with HTTPS) and it will be arrive to my private IP on spesific port. Otherwise, when others hit my domain it still directed to my public IP and public directory.

**For example**

```
If spesific IP:
192.168.x.x -> https://example.com -> IP_public -> NAT -> IP_private:port
```

```
If others IP:
Others IP -> https://example.com -> IP_public
```

Could you please give me a suggest how can I do this?

Comment: Nginx doesn't handle NAT, it sounds like you're using it as a proxy. You'll likely need to make these changes at your router/firewall/whatever actually handles NAT in your case. you can set up an Nginx route to only allow connections from a specific IP by adding `allow 192.168.x.x` to the server object of your Nginx config.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438867/how-can-i-allow-access-to-a-single-ip-address-via-nginx-conf for a complete example of allowing a specific IP/range for a particular route.

Comment: Hi @Joseph, thank you for your suggest. I'm on VPN connection and I have done setting up iptables to routing from that specific IP to another IP in my internals, but client want to access it with name-based and ssl certificate too. Example above is their explanation about it and I have no idea with it. It's why I using nginx at first time and it's wrong. I need to still using the tunnel VPN while using SSL too. Any better idea with this?