# docker nginx django ALLOWED_HOSTS not allowing requests through

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

I am deploying an api that doesn't require database or gunicorn to be used. With following configurations I am setting up the api:

nginx.conf

```
upstream django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

nginx Dockerfile

```
# Base image for building the Django application
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

`ALLOWED_HOSTS` django settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

`Dockerfile`

```
# Base image for building the Django application
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 80

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noreload
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/code
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
```

The purpose is to create an api which will only be called by other client like a Python based client. I am testing this from my local machine but not working. Adding * wildcard works but is too risky. So, what changes should I make for following two cases:

**1. To be able to call from my local python client.**

**2. To be able to call from some other ip address and block rest of the ip addresses.**

Comment: You can specify the allowable IP's in your `nginx.conf` as `allow   my.public.ip.here` .

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438867/how-can-i-allow-access-to-a-single-ip-address-via-nginx-conf

Answer (score 0):

I have Django and Nginx in Docker containers with the same nginx.conf file as yours, and I was getting "disallowed host" error from Django. So, I added 'django' to 'ALLOWED_HOSTS' and it fixed the problem. My 'ALLOWED_HOSTS':

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=http://django,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,django
```

So, probably you can add 'django' to 'ALLOWED_HOSTS' to avoid using * wildcard.